# Calling a contract from another contract: issue with paramenter passing

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

I have two cntracts with one calling the other. 
The first is

```
contract A_int
{
    event called(string str,uint ts,address addr,string tr);
    function callme(address addr,uint ts,string tr)
    {
        called("called me",ts,addr,tr);
    }
    function kill()
        { 
        suicide(msg.sender);
        }
}
```

and another contract which calls this contract

```
contract caller_tracker_string
{
    address curr_tracker;
    address owner; 
    function change_contract(address addr)
    {
        curr_tracker=addr;
    }
    function caller_tracker_string(address current_trcker)
    {
        owner=tx.origin;
        curr_tracker=current_trcker;        
    }
    function adduser(address usr_new,uint ts,string tr)
    {
        curr_tracker.call(bytes4(sha3("callme(address,uint256,string)")),usr_new,ts,tr);
    }
    function kill()
        { 
        suicide(owner);
        }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that the string argument is not getting logged in contract A's log event. why could that be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You would do well to tidy up your code with short expressive names. You would then notice that your presumed constructor `function caller_tracker` has a name that does not match that of your contract `caller_tracker_string`. This results in `curr_tracker` being always `0`, so `A_int` is never called.

Comment: Did spelling the constructor correctly fix your issue?

Comment: No. I am still not able to call the second contract correctly. It is still logging empty string for tr value

Comment: I was finally able to call another contract using the below method.  A_int a=A_int(curr_tracker); a.callme(addr,ts,"hi");. But still dont know why the above method does not work.